# link is not working in header file after complete loading in chrome and opera

Tags: email, url

please visit this link :

on right top, you can see link : "Email us", it is clickable when the page is loading , after it complete wepage loaded, i can not able to click on "Email us". That's link is not working.

please help me to find some solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about css

Comment: It is working properly...

Comment: Hi Dexter thanks a lot for reply. Ya after i applied Marius solution, It's working now....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've been through this before.
I don't remember the exact question.
There is a div going over your header.
The element is the one with the class `.header-bottom`. It has the `top -70px` and `z-index:10`

Comment: Ya, you are right, it was working before, but all in a  sudeen i don't know what happened? So what i have to change now with that .header-bottom? please help me.

Comment: hi, i got it, thanks a lot for your help  , you are awesome.... as now in future also please help me again , again & again....

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn how to debug CSS issues, just use the Developer Tools from Chrome or Firebug from Firefox to get a view like this:

[image]

So you know what the problem is and can adjust the CSS accordingly.